# Why is using an interface implementation with generics in .NET 7 so slow in WebAssembly?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, webassembly

The following method runs pretty fast on the browser when compiled to WebAssembly (WASM):

```
public static int SumInt(int[] vals)
{
    int sum = default;

    for (int i = 0; i < vals.Length; i++)
        sum += vals[i];

    return sum;
}
```

In my timing tests (where the method is called 100 times with 1,000,000 numbers each time), it took about 70 ms to run.

In trying to make this method generic (in order to handle other primitive types, like `float` and `double`), I wrote the following:

```
private static T Sum<T>(T[] vals, IAdder<T> adder) where T : struct
{
    T sum = default;

    for (int i = 0; i < vals.Length; i++)
        sum = adder.Add(sum, vals[i]);

    return sum;
}

public interface IAdder<T> where T : struct
{
    public T Add(T x, T y);
}

public class AdderInt : IAdder<int>
{
    public int Add(int x, int y) => x + y;
}
```

So that I can define the following method for integers:

```
public static int Sum(int[] vals) => Sum(vals, new AdderInt());
```

However, for the same timing test as before, this new implementation took about 1000 ms to run. That's over 14 times slower.

When I'm not running this code in WebAssembly but in a .NET application, they both take about the same amount of time.

Any ideas of what's going on or suggestions for improving the code in order to handle other types in a performant way (but also avoid code duplication)?

Comment: To get to an assessment, one would probably have to look at the result of the compilation. If that latter is not somehow translated into something _very_ similar to the former code, then I'd expect at least _some_ performance penalty for a function-call overhead, for example. I _would_ expect this to be somehow inlined but honestly, I have no idea how much this will / can be optimized.

Comment: Doesn't answer your perf question, but FYI, you can just add directly if you constrain `T` to `INumber<T>`.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/generics/math

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint That's pretty cool. Unfortunately, it's slow, too. Here are my results: original SumInt: 77 ms; LINQ: 262 ms; INumber<T>: 415 ms.

Answer (score -1):

For C# 7 you want something like this

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] int_array = { 7, 3, -2, 1, 8 };
        float[] float_array = { 7, 3, -2, 1, 8 };
        double[] double_array = { 7, 3, -2, 1, 8 };
        Vector2[] vector_array = { new Vector2(7, 1), new Vector2(-2, 3), new Vector2(1, 8) };

        int int_sum = Sum(int_array);
        float float_sum = Sum(float_array);
        double double_sum = Sum(double_array);
        Vector2 vector_sum = Sum(vector_array);

        Console.WriteLine($"sum({string.Join(",", int_array)}) = {int_sum}");
        Console.WriteLine($"sum({string.Join(",", float_array)}) = {float_sum}");
        Console.WriteLine($"sum({string.Join(",", double_array)}) = {double_sum}");
        Console.WriteLine($"sum({string.Join(",", vector_array)}) = {vector_sum}");
    }

    static T Sum<T>(params T[] items)
    {
        if (items.Length==0) return default(T);
        if (items.Length==1) return items[0];
        var add = Operation<T>.Add;
        T sum = items[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < items.Length; i++)
        {
            sum = add(sum, items[i]);
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

with output

```
sum(7,3,-2,1,8) = 17
sum(7,3,-2,1,8) = 17
sum(7,3,-2,1,8) = 17
sum(<7, 1>,<-2, 3>,<1, 8>) = <6, 12>
```

which you do with the following class `Operation<T>` which generates functions by emitting ILcode.

Not only it works with primitive types, but also with derived types as long as the appropriate operator is defined. As a test above I used `System.Numerics.Vector2`.

For the `Sum()` function repeated calls to `Operation<T>.Add` are needed.

#### `Operation.cs`

```
/* Copyright (C) 2007  The Trustees of Indiana University
 *
 * Use, modification and distribution is subject to the Boost Software
 * License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at
 * http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
 *  
 * Authors: Douglas Gregor
 *          Andrew Lumsdaine
 *          
 * Url:     http://www.osl.iu.edu/research/mpi.net/svn/
 * 
 * This file provides the "Operations" class, which contains common
 * reduction operations such as addition and multiplication for any 
 * type.
 * 
 * This code was heavily influenced by Keith Farmer's
 *   Operator Overloading with Generics
 * at http://www.codeproject.com/csharp/genericoperators.asp
 * 
 * All MPI related code removed by John Alexiou. Code retains the dynamic
 * operator generators of 
 */
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{

    /// <summary>
    /// The <c>Operation</c> class provides reduction operations for use with the
    /// reduction collectives.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// The <c>Operation</c> class is used with the reduction collective communication operations
    /// For example, the <see cref="Add"/> property is a delegate that adds two data of type
    /// <typeparamref name="T"/>, while <see cref="Min"/> returns the minimum of the
    /// two data. The reduction operations provided by this class should be 
    /// preferred to hand-written reduction operations (particularly for built-in types)
    /// because it enables additional optimizations in the MPI library.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of data used in these operations.</typeparam>
    public class Operation<T>
    {
        #region Function Generators
        /// <summary>
        /// Synthesize a new UnaryFunction associated with a given operation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name">The name of the function to build, e.g., "add".</arg>
        /// <param name="opCode">The <c>OpCode</c> used for primitive types.</arg>
        /// <param name="methodName">The name of the overloaded function used for class types.</arg>
        /// <returns>Returns a new delegate implementing the given operation.</returns>
        public static Func<T, T> BuildUnaryFunction(string name, OpCode opCode, string methodName)
        {
            return BuildUnaryFunction<T, T>(name, opCode, methodName);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Synthesize a new UnaryFunction associated with a given operation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name">The name of the function to build, e.g., "add".</arg>
        /// <param name="opCode">The <c>OpCode</c> used for primitive types.</arg>
        /// <param name="methodName">The name of the overloaded function used for class types.</arg>
        /// <typeparam name="M">The argument type</typeparam>
        /// <typeparam name="R">The return type</typeparam>      
        /// <returns>Returns a new delegate implementing the given operation.</returns>
        public static Func<M, R> BuildUnaryFunction<M, R>(string name, OpCode opCode, string methodName)
        {
            // Build the new mpiDelegateMethod
            DynamicMethod method =
                new DynamicMethod(
                    name+":"+typeof(T).ToString(),
                    typeof(R),
                    new Type[] { typeof(M) },
                    typeof(Operation<T>));

            ILGenerator generator = method.GetILGenerator();

            // Load the arguments onto the stack
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);

            if (typeof(T).IsPrimitive)
            {
                // Emit the op-code for primitive types, and we're done.
                generator.Emit(opCode);
            }
            else
            {
                // Find the overloaded operator and create a call to it
                MethodInfo opMethod = typeof(T).GetMethod(methodName, new Type[] { typeof(M) });
                if (opMethod!=null)
                {
                    generator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, opMethod, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new MissingMemberException(
                        string.Format("Method {0}({1}) Not Found.",
                        methodName,
                        typeof(T).Name));
                }
            }

            // Return the intermediate
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            // Return a delegate to call the mpiDelegateMethod
            return (Func<M, R>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<M, R>));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Synthesize a new Constructor.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TArg">The argument type for the function</typeparam>
        /// <arg name="name">The name of the function to build, e.g., "add".</arg>
        /// <arg name="opCode">The <c>OpCode</c> used for primitive types.</arg>
        /// <arg name="methodName">The name of the overloaded function used for class types.</arg>
        /// <returns>Returns a new delegate implementing the given operation.</returns>
        public static Func<TArg, T> BuildConstructor<TArg>()
        {
            // Build the new mpiDelegateMethod
            DynamicMethod method =
                new DynamicMethod(
                    "new:"+typeof(T).ToString(),
                    typeof(T),
                    new Type[] { typeof(TArg) },
                    typeof(Operation<T>));

            ILGenerator generator = method.GetILGenerator();
            LocalBuilder local_var = generator.DeclareLocal(typeof(T));
            Label lbl = generator.DefineLabel();

            // Find the overloaded operator and create a call to it
            ConstructorInfo opMethod = typeof(T).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(TArg) });

            if (opMethod!=null)
            {

                // Load the arguments onto the stack
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, opMethod);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Br_S, lbl);
                generator.MarkLabel(lbl);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new MissingMemberException(
                    string.Format("Constructor {0}({1}) Not Found.",
                    typeof(T).Name,
                    typeof(TArg).Name));
            }

            // Return the intermediate
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            // Return a delegate to call the mpiDelegateMethod
            return (Func<TArg, T>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<TArg, T>));
        }

        public static Func<TArg1, TArg2, T> BuildConstructor<TArg1, TArg2>()
        {
            // Build the new mpiDelegateMethod
            DynamicMethod method =
                new DynamicMethod(
                    "new:"+typeof(T).ToString(),
                    typeof(T),
                    new Type[] { typeof(TArg1), typeof(TArg2) },
                    typeof(Operation<T>));

            ILGenerator generator = method.GetILGenerator();
            LocalBuilder local_var = generator.DeclareLocal(typeof(T));
            Label lbl = generator.DefineLabel();

            // Find the overloaded operator and create a call to it
            ConstructorInfo opMethod = typeof(T).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(TArg1), typeof(TArg2) });

            if (opMethod!=null)
            {

                // Load the arguments onto the stack
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, opMethod);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Br_S, lbl);
                generator.MarkLabel(lbl);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new MissingMemberException(
                    string.Format("Constructor {0}({1},{2}) Not Found.",
                    typeof(T).Name,
                    typeof(TArg1).Name,
                    typeof(TArg2).Name));
            }

            // Return the intermediate
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            // Return a delegate to call the mpiDelegateMethod
            return (Func<TArg1, TArg2, T>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<TArg1, TArg2, T>));

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Synthesize a new BinaryFunction associated with a given operation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <arg name="name">The name of the function to build, e.g., "add".</arg>
        /// <arg name="opCode">The <c>OpCode</c> used for primitive types.</arg>
        /// <arg name="methodName">The name of the overloaded function used for class types.</arg>
        /// <returns>Returns a new delegate implementing the given operation.</returns>
        public static Func<T, T, T> BuildBinaryFunction(string name, OpCode opCode, string methodName)
        {
            // Build the new mpiDelegateMethod
            DynamicMethod method =
                new DynamicMethod(
                    name+":"+typeof(T).ToString(),
                    typeof(T),
                    new Type[] { typeof(T), typeof(T) },
                    typeof(Operation<T>));

            ILGenerator generator = method.GetILGenerator();

            // Load the arguments onto the stack
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);

            if (typeof(T).IsPrimitive)
            {
                // Emit the op-code for primitive types, and we're done.
                generator.Emit(opCode);
            }
            else
            {
                // Find the overloaded operator and create a call to it
                MethodInfo opMethod = typeof(T).GetMethod(methodName, new Type[] { typeof(T), typeof(T) });
                if (opMethod!=null)
                {
                    generator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, opMethod, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new MissingMemberException(
                        string.Format("Method {0}({1},{2}) Not Found.",
                        methodName,
                        typeof(T).Name,
                        typeof(T).Name));
                }
            }

            // Return the intermediate
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            // Return a delegate to call the mpiDelegateMethod
            return (Func<T, T, T>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, T, T>));
        }

        public static Func<T, T, R> BuildBinaryFunction<R>(string name, OpCode opCode, string methodName)
        {
            // Build the new mpiDelegateMethod
            DynamicMethod method =
                new DynamicMethod(
                    name+":"+typeof(T).ToString(),
                    typeof(R),
                    new Type[] { typeof(T), typeof(T) },
                    typeof(Operation<T>));

            ILGenerator generator = method.GetILGenerator();

            // Load the arguments onto the stack
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);

            if (typeof(T).IsPrimitive)
            {
                // Emit the op-code for primitive types, and we're done.
                generator.Emit(opCode);
            }
            else
            {
                // Find the overloaded operator and create a call to it
                MethodInfo opMethod = typeof(T).GetMethod(methodName, new Type[] { typeof(T), typeof(T) });
                if (opMethod!=null)
                {
                    generator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, opMethod, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new MissingMemberException(
                        string.Format("Method {0}({1},{2}) Not Found.",
                        methodName,
                        typeof(T).Name,
                        typeof(T).Name));
                }
            }

            // Return the intermediate
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            // Return a delegate to call the mpiDelegateMethod
            return (Func<T, T, R>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, T, R>));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Synthesize a new BinaryFunction associated with a given operation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <arg name="name">The name of the function to build, e.g., "add".</arg>
        /// <arg name="opCode">The <c>OpCode</c> used for primitive types.</arg>
        /// <arg name="methodName">The name of the overloaded function used for class types.</arg>
        /// <returns>Returns a new delegate implementing the given operation.</returns>
        public static Func<L, R, T> BuildBinaryFunction<L, R>(string name, OpCode opCode, string methodName)
        {
            // Build the new mpiDelegateMethod
            DynamicMethod method =
                new DynamicMethod(
                    name+":"+typeof(T).ToString(),
                    typeof(T),
                    new Type[] { typeof(L), typeof(R) },
                    typeof(Operation<T>));

            ILGenerator generator = method.GetILGenerator();

            // Load the arguments onto the stack
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);

            if (typeof(T).IsPrimitive)
            {
                // Emit the op-code for primitive types, and we're done.
                generator.Emit(opCode);
            }
            else
            {
                // Find the overloaded operator and create a call to it
                MethodInfo opMethod = typeof(T).GetMethod(methodName, new Type[] { typeof(L), typeof(R) });
                if (opMethod!=null)
                {
                    generator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, opMethod, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new MissingMemberException(
                        string.Format("Method {0}({1},{2}) Not Found.",
                        methodName,
                        typeof(L).Name,
                        typeof(R).Name));
                }
            }

            // Return the intermediate
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

            // Return a delegate to call the mpiDelegateMethod
            return (Func<L, R, T>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<L, R, T>));
        }

        #endregion

        #region Minimum and maximum
        /// <summary>
        /// Cached intermediate of the reduction operation that computes the minimum of 
        /// two data.
        /// </summary>
        private static Func<T, T, T> min = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Reduction operation that computes the minimum of two data.
        /// </summary>
        public static Func<T, T, T> Min
        {
            get
            {
                if (min==null)
                {
                    // Build the new mpiDelegateMethod
                    DynamicMethod method =
                        new DynamicMethod(
                            "min:"+typeof(T).ToString(),
                            typeof(T),
                            new Type[] { typeof(T), typeof(T) },
                            typeof(Operation<T>));

                    ILGenerator generator = method.GetILGenerator();

                    // Load the arguments onto the stack
                    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);

                    Label ifLess = generator.DefineLabel();

                    if (typeof(T).IsPrimitive)
                    {
                        // Compare the two operands with "<" and jump to ifLess if they are equal
                        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Blt_S, ifLess);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Find the overloaded "<" operator
                        MethodInfo opMethod = typeof(T).GetMethod("op_LessThan", new Type[] { typeof(T), typeof(T) });
                        if (opMethod==null)
                        {
                            throw new ArgumentException("Type "+typeof(T).Name+" does not have a < operator");
                        }

                        // Create a call to the "<" operator
                        generator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, opMethod, null);

                        // If the intermediate was "1" (true), jump to ifLess
                        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Brtrue_S, ifLess);
                    }

                    // We're in the fall-through case, where the first argument is not less than the second.

                    // Load the second argument
                    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);

                    // Return the intermediate
                    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

                    // Label the case where the first argument is less than the second
                    generator.MarkLabel(ifLess);

                    // Load the first argument 
                    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);

                    // Return the intermediate
                    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

                    // Create the delegate to call the mpiDelegateMethod
                    min=(Func<T, T, T>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, T, T>));
                }
                return min;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Cached intermediate of the reduction operation that computes the maximum of 
        /// two data.
        /// </summary>
        private static Func<T, T, T> max = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Reduction operation that computes the maximum of two data.
        /// </summary>
        public static Func<T, T, T> Max
        {
            get
            {
                if (max==null)
                {
                    // Build the new mpiDelegateMethod
                    DynamicMethod method =
                        new DynamicMethod(
                            "max:"+typeof(T).ToString(),
                            typeof(T),
                            new Type[] { typeof(T), typeof(T) },
                            typeof(Operation<T>));

                    ILGenerator generator = method.GetILGenerator();

                    // Load the arguments onto the stack
                    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);

                    Label ifLess = generator.DefineLabel();

                    if (typeof(T).IsPrimitive)
                    {
                        // Compare the two operands with "<" and jump to ifLess if they are equal
                        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Blt_S, ifLess);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Find the overloaded "<" operator
                        MethodInfo opMethod = typeof(T).GetMethod("op_LessThan", new Type[] { typeof(T), typeof(T) });
                        if (opMethod==null)
                        {
                            throw new ArgumentException("Type "+typeof(T).Name+" does not have a < operator");
                        }

                        // Create a call to the "<" operator
                        generator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, opMethod, null);

                        // If the intermediate was "1" (true), jump to ifLess
                        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Brtrue_S, ifLess);
                    }

                    // We're in the fall-through case, where the first argument is not less than the second.

                    // Load the first argument
                    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);

                    // Return the intermediate
                    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

                    // Label the case where the first argument is less than the second
                    generator.MarkLabel(ifLess);

                    // Load the second argument 
                    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);

                    // Return the intermediate
                    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

                    // Create the delegate to call the mpiDelegateMethod
                    max=(Func<T, T, T>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, T, T>));
                }
                return max;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Arithmetics
        /// <summary>
        /// Reduction operation that adds two data.
        /// </summary>
        public static Func<T, T, T> Add
        {
            get
            {
                if (typeof(T)==typeof(string))
                {
                    return BuildBinaryFunction("add", OpCodes.Add, "Concat");
                }
                else
                {
                    return BuildBinaryFunction("add", OpCodes.Add, "op_Addition");
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Reduction operation that subs two data.
        /// </summary>
        public static Func<T, T, T> Sub => BuildBinaryFunction("sub", OpCodes.Sub, "op_Subtraction");

        /// <summary>
        /// Reduction operation that negates a value.
        /// </summary>
        public static Func<T, T> Neg => BuildUnaryFunction("neg", OpCodes.Neg, "op_Negate");

        /// <summary>
        /// Reduction operation that multiply two data.
        /// </summary>
        public static Func<T, T, T> Mul => BuildBinaryFunction("multiply", OpCodes.Mul, "op_Multiply");

        public static Func<L, R, T> BuildMultiply<L, R>()
        {
            var multiply2 = BuildBinaryFunction<L, R>("multiply", OpCodes.Mul, "op_Multiply");
            return (Func<L, R, T>)multiply2;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Reduction operation that divides two data.
        /// </summary>
        public static Func<T, T, T> Div => BuildBinaryFunction("div", OpCodes.Div, "op_Divide");
        public static Func<T, T, bool> Gt => BuildBinaryFunction<bool>("gt", OpCodes.Cgt, "op_GreaterThan");
        public static Func<T, T, bool> Lt => BuildBinaryFunction<bool>("lt", OpCodes.Clt, "op_LessThan");

        #endregion

        #region Logical operations
        /// <summary>
        /// Reduction operation that computes the logical AND of two data,
        /// including integral types.
        /// </summary>
        public static Func<T, T, T> LogicalAnd => BuildBinaryFunction("logicalAnd", OpCodes.And, "op_LogicalAnd");

        /// <summary>
        /// Reduction operation that computes the logical OR of two data,
        /// including integral types.
        /// </summary>
        public static Func<T, T, T> LogicalOr => BuildBinaryFunction("logicalOr", OpCodes.Or, "op_LogicalOr");
        #endregion

        #region Bitwise operations

        /// <summary>
        /// Reduction operation that computes the bitwise AND of two data.
        /// </summary>
        public static Func<T, T, T> BitwiseAnd => BuildBinaryFunction("bitwiseAnd", OpCodes.And, "op_BitwiseAnd");

        /// <summary>
        /// Reduction operation that computes the bitwise OR of two data.
        /// </summary>
        public static Func<T, T, T> BitwiseOr => BuildBinaryFunction("bitwiseOr", OpCodes.Or, "op_BitwiseOr");


        /// <summary>
        /// Reduction operation that computes the bitwise exclusive OR of two data.
        /// </summary>
        public static Func<T, T, T> ExclusiveOr => BuildBinaryFunction("exclusiveOr", OpCodes.Xor, "op_ExclusiveOr");
        #endregion

        #region Datatype categorization
        /// <summary>
        /// The kind of MPI datatype. MPI classifies the predefined data types into 
        /// several different categories. This classification is used primarily to determine 
        /// which predefined reduction operations are supported by the low-level MPI
        /// implementation.
        /// </summary>
        internal enum DatatypeKind
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// C integer types, such as the predefined integral types in C# and .NET.
            /// </summary>
            CInteger,

            /// <summary>
            /// Fortran integer types. At present, there are no C# or .NET types that 
            /// are classified this way.
            /// </summary>
            FortranInteger,

            /// <summary>
            /// Floating point types, such as the predefined <c>float</c> and <c>double</c> types.
            /// </summary>
            FloatingPoint,

            /// <summary>
            /// The MPI logical type. At present, there are no C# or .NET types that 
            /// are classified this way.
            /// </summary>
            Logical,

            /// <summary>
            /// The MPI complex type. At present, there are no C# or .NET types that 
            /// are classified this way.
            /// </summary>
            Complex,

            /// <summary>
            /// The MPI byte type, which corresponds to the <c>byte</c> type in C#.
            /// </summary>
            Byte,

            /// <summary>
            /// Any type that does not fit into one of the other MPI datatype classifications.
            /// </summary>
            Other
        }

        ///// <summary>
        ///// The MPI datatype classification of the type <typeparamref name="TEventArgs"/>.
        ///// </summary>
        //internal static DatatypeKind Kind=GetDatatypeKind();

        /// <summary>
        ///   Retrieves the kind of datatype for the type <typeparamref name="TEventArgs"/>. 
        ///   Used only to initialize <see cref="Kind"/>.
        /// </summary>
        private static DatatypeKind GetDatatypeKind()
        {
            if (!typeof(T).IsPrimitive)
            {
                // Non-primitive types don'editbox fit any of the MPI datatype categories
                return DatatypeKind.Other;
            }

            // C Integer types
            if (typeof(T)==typeof(short)||typeof(T)==typeof(ushort)
                ||typeof(T)==typeof(int)||typeof(T)==typeof(uint)
                ||typeof(T)==typeof(long)||typeof(T)==typeof(ulong))
            {
                return DatatypeKind.CInteger;
            }

            // Floating point types
            if (typeof(T)==typeof(float)||typeof(T)==typeof(double))
            {
                return DatatypeKind.FloatingPoint;
            }

            // Deal with other kinds of types (future?)
            return DatatypeKind.Other;
        }
        #endregion


    }

}
```

The above reusable class has static properties of `Operation<T>` which do math with any `T` type as long as an appropriate `operator` is defined.

An example would be the

```
public static Func<T, T, T> Multiply { get; }
```

property that returns the appropriate multiplication operator.

Comment: Unfortunately, this way took 13726 ms (about 200 times slower than the original).

Comment: Ok, I have another option. To emit IL code. I will update you soon.

Comment: @redcurry - ok try this `Operation<T>` above. It should be as close to concrete code as possible as it emits the code as needed.

Comment: It's still taking a very long time for me.

Comment: @redcurry - thank you for checking. I guess what you can do at this point is overload methods to accept different types instead of having one method for all generic types.

Comment: Yeah, but does that mean I have to duplicate the code for each type?

Comment: @redcurry - yes, it does. It's a bummer, but that is how .NET was built to begin with. Later versions do support generic math, although I do not know if they are performant.

Comment: Thanks. I tried using INumber<T>, but it was 4 times slower.